# How to resolve FATAL: connection limit exceeded for non-superusers

Tags: java, postgresql

I have written a java code for bulk insertion. I'm using the copy command for importing and creating different connection objects for different tables, but while executing, the program it is throwing the following errors:

```
FATAL: connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
```

Comment: My bet is that you are not closing the connections properly from within your Java code.

Comment: Are you by chance creating a new connection for every insert?

Answer (score 12):

You have exceeded the connection limit of PostgreSQL server. There are some reserved connection for Super user.

To increase the connection limit you have to change the postgresql.conf (default 100)
it is located on your PostgreSQL data directory.

```
cat postgresql.conf | grep max_connection max_connections = 100
        # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)
```

Increase the limit and restart the PostgreSQL instance.

Warning: increasing the connection limit will affect the memory.

try optimizing connection using connection pooling either in application or db layer.
on PostgreSQL you can use [Pgpool2](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: Or you can try killing the connections.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a connection pool? Check if connections are closed properly in your code. This should be done in a try-finally block:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
try {
    ....
}
finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

If you really need a large amount of connections, set the max_connections-property in postres accordingly.

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html)