# How to find which application reserved Postgres connections?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

There are several applications running on Tomcat. They use Postgres databases and sometimes exceed the max connection limit:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:684)
```

I have tried to increase the limit ([How to resolve FATAL: connection limit exceeded for non-superusers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581901/how-to-resolve-fatal-connection-limit-exceeded-for-non-superusers)) but the problem remains. How to find out which application takes over connection slots?

Comment: add ApplicationName to cs, like here: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/MyDB?ApplicationName=MyApp` then you will see it in `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: Is there any way to see a historical activity?

Comment: if you save pg_stat_activity periodically somewhere, sure. but historically `application_name` will not be set to your value...

Comment: Dėkui. Currently I haven't reached the limit but are some strange states "idle in transaction'.

Comment: I sveikata. `idle in transaction` usually appear when you use pgbouncer or other pooler/session manager that uses pool_mode = transaction. I can give wider answer if you ask a question on that

Comment: Created new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803627/hibernate-and-postgres-pg-stat-activity-shows-many-rows-with-state-idle-in-tr

Comment: answered with example - got maybe tl;dr, but hope will give the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add ApplicationName to the connection string, like here:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/MyDB?ApplicationName=MyApp
```

then you will see it in:

```
select application_name, count(1), state 
from pg_stat_activity 
group by application_name, state;
```

This will work only if you have separate connection strings for different applications of course.

Also check some [info](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/datasource.html) on connections pooling with JDBC.